# Re.sub in python not working

Tags: python, regex

Suppose that:

```
s = '<A HREF="http://www.google.com" ID="test">blah</A>'
```

I want to prepend the url with "url: ", so I tried:

```
s = re.sub(r'href="([\w:/.]+)"', "url: " + r'\1', s, re.I)
```

but this does not change `s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the other answer is technically absolutely correct, I don't think you want that what is mentionned there.

Instead, you might want to work with a match object:

```
m = re.search(r'href="([\w:/.]+)"', s, re.I)
print m.expand(r"url: \1")
```

which results to

```
url: http://google.com
```

without the `<A` before and the `ID="test">blah</A>` behind.

(If you want to do more of these replacements, you might even want to reuse the regex by compiling it:

```
r = re.compile(r'href="([\w:/.]+)"', re.I)
ex = lambda st: r.search(st).expand(r"url: \1")
print ex('<A HREF="http://www.google.com" ID="test">blah</A>')
print ex('<A HREF="http://www.yahoo.com" ID="test">blah</A>')
# and so on.
```

---

If, however, you indeed want to keep the HTML around it, you'll have to work with lookahead and lookbehind expressions:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=href=")([\w:/.]+)(?=")', "url: " + r'\1', s, flags=re.I)
# -> '<A HREF="url: http://www.google.com" ID="test">blah</A>'
```

or simply by repeating the omitted stuff:

```
re.sub(r'href="([\w:/.]+)"', r'href="url: \1"', s, flags=re.I)
# -> '<A href="url: http://www.google.com" ID="test">blah</A>'
```

Comment: I actually want to keep the html in there and do the replacement right inside.

Comment: No problem sir, i appreciate your help. can you help me with my question above?

Answer (score 4):

The `re.I` is in the wrong position (it's being interpreted as the `count` argument).

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
                              ^^^^^    ^^^^^
```

Try:

```
In [27]: re.sub(r'href="([\w:/.]+)"', "url: " + r'\1', s, flags=re.I)
Out[27]: '<A url: http://www.google.com ID="test">blah</A>'
```

Comment: Thank you! If I may also ask (I'm a regex noob), how do I use regex to modify `s` such that only the url is prepended with "url: ", not the entire match? (in other words, keep `HREF=` in the string)